# How to turn off multivalue in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

How can i turn off the multivalued in solr?

I tried to edit the manage-schema file inside /data_driven_schema_configs/conf/ folder and set all multivalued="true" to false.

Then restart solr and then create new collection, but nothing changed.

I need this because i need to sort my data in the table in banana ui.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create your own schema.xml in the "/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/" or rename the current managedschema to schema.xml

After that change settings in

\conf\solrconfig.xml

add `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` to `solarconfig.xml`

After this change you can modify the `schema.xml` and restart the server.

The changes made will be reflected to your fields.

Comment: Thanks, @Abhijit Bashetti, it is working as expected by just adding as you mentioned. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Is there any way by which this could be done through the UI of the solr?

Comment: @BARATH : As far as I know, it could not be done from the UI of the solr.